# scrapy requires Python 2.7 but already it is

Tags: python, scrapy

I installed Python 2.7 and then tried to install `scrapy` via `pip`. It didn't work, so I deleted `scrapy` and tried to install again via `pip`.  When I do I get the following errors:

```
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:192359: error: âxsltDocDefaultLoaderâ undeclared (first use in this function)

src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:192368: error: âxsltDocLoaderFuncâ undeclared (first use in this function)

src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:192368: error: expected â)â before â__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree__xslt_doc_loaderâ

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-fiN0SO-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/lxml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.4.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.6.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 148, in main
    return command.main(args[1:], options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.6.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 169, in main
    text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 81: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I then try to run `scrapy`, but it complains that it requires Python 2.7.  As you can see from the screenshot below, I am running version 2.7.  Any ideas what is wrong?

[image]

Comment: Check, but I think scrapy requires lxml which is a binary. You might need to install some prerequisites via your system's package manager, rather than pip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traceback shows that you are using `pip` from python 2.6.

How have you installed python 2.7? Depending on your system, you might have available a `pip2.7` command. Otherwise you could try installing pip for your python 2.7:

```
$ wget https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py
$ python get-pip.py
```

You might need to use `sudo` for the last command. Once you have pip installed, it's highly recommended to use `virtualenv` (`pip install virtualenv`) to install the new dependencies and not mess up with your system installation.

Alternatively, if you install the latest `pip`, you can use the option `--user` to install packages locally without requiring sudo: `pip install --user scrapy`.

Also, it seems you have problems installing `lxml`. What distribution of linux are you using? Have you installed the libraries libxml2-dev and libxslt-dev?

Verify that you have the prerequisites for scrapy and lxml and refer to your package manager in case of any missing library:

- http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html
- http://lxml.de/installation.html

Comment: im using centos. 

`File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 185, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, in main
    text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 81: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: Are you using latest `pip`? Can you add the full output? This seems related to https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1137

Comment: Where is the latest pip ? I use the script here to install and I  get the same error.https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py Thanks.

Comment: @user1965449, that's the latest. You will have to look in detail to the traceback before to error to figure out what dependency you are mising. That error is causing pip to fail due to encoding issues in the error message and thus hindering the real error.